# Successively resampling rows into columns of a data frame (for time series analysis)

Tags: r, resampling

I've an exemplary data frame df:

```
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  6 11
2  2  7 12
3  3  8 13
4  4  9 14
5  5 10 15
```

Now I want to resample this data frame in the following way:

Go to the first row and extract k (e.g. 3) rows and convert them into columns/vector:

```
1  6 11  2  7 12  3  8 13
```

Then, go to the second row and do the same:

```
2  7 12  3  8 13  4  9 14
```

For the third row it's

```
3  8 13  4  9 14  5 10 15
```

and so on...

At the end all resampled rows aka vectors should be rbind to a new data frame.

I've played a lot around finding an efficient solution, but all implementations are very slow.

How can I solve my problem efficiently?

Comment: I am assuming you're doing it for `LSTM` time-series framework, aren't you?

Comment: I have provided an alternative solution.

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Yes, you are right! From KPSS tests and PACF analysis I figure out the optimal number of differences and lags. Especially the number of lags is the information needed for resampling the training and test data sets to build a 3d-array used within keras.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. I've placed the results into a list, but they can just as easily be `cbind`ed into a dataframe.

```
dlist<-list()
for(i in 1:(nrow(data)-2)) {
  dlist[[i]]<-matrix(t(data[i:(i+2),]),nrow=1)
  }

dlist
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    6   11    2    7   12    3    8   13

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    2    7   12    3    8   13    4    9   14

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    3    8   13    4    9   14    5   10   15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. At the end I run `do.call(rbind, dlist)` and get my final data frame. I was really surprised that working on a list is so much faster then working on a data frame within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question! So, I am just putting this alternative solution up here in case I will come back looking for it in the future :-)

```
library(purrr)

map((nrow(df) - 1):0,~c(t(df[(nrow(df) - .x):nrow(df),]))[1:(k * ncol(df))]) %>% 
  do.call(rbind,.)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    6   11    2    7   12    3    8   13
[2,]    2    7   12    3    8   13    4    9   14
[3,]    3    8   13    4    9   14    5   10   15
[4,]    4    9   14    5   10   15   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    5   10   15   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Obviously, we can filter out `NA`-s, but I believe this is more general solution.